# rxjava android retryWhen not calling onError on last attempt

Tags: android, android-activity, rx-java

I have this code to attemp to connect to a xmpp server. Everything works fine except in the last attemp to try to connect, onError is not called on the subscriber and according to the doc, it should. What am i doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void connect(final AbstractXMPPConnection connection) {
    Observable.<AbstractXMPPConnection>create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
        })
         .retryWhen(attempts -> attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 4), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {
             return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         }))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AbstractXMPPConnection>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                     if (callback != null)
                        callback.onFailedConnecting();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AbstractXMPPConnection conn) {
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onConnected();
                }
            });
}
```

TLDR: on the last attempt, public void onError should be called and it is not

Comment: I think you need to flatMap in an error() observable for the retryWhen to throw.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
.retryWhen(attempts -> attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 4), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {        
   return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}))
```

this code will never emit an error so it will try exponentially (Timer) to retry but will never fail. Thus onError() will never be called.

If you want to catch the error either you need to pass it from the retryWhen with an explicit Observable.error() or delete the retryWhen part. :)

Comment: How to explicit pass it from the retryWhen ?

Comment: Further in the chain? `Observable.onError(throwable)` e.g. `if(throwable instanceOf IllegalStateException){ return onError(throwable } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I made this such way (Scala, RxScala):

```
.retryWhen(_
    .zipWith(Observable.just(1, 2, 3, -1))((t, i) => (t, i))
    .flatMap( tuple => tuple match {
      case (t, -1) => Observable.error(t)
      case (t, i) => Observable.timer(i seconds)
    }))
```

Maybe there is some kind of `zipWith` operator, which calls `onError`, with first non-pair element. It would be nice